# how should I use jsx in dictionary

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to use jsx in dict like below

```
var customJSX = React.createClass({ // some code });

dict = {
  foo: customJSX,
}

var foo = 'foo';
```

when I call get error the second one.

```
<dict.foo />  // right
<dict[foo] />  // wrong
```

how should I call it from dictionary when I don't know key?

thanks for your time.

Comment: You can assign component to variable and then render it - https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/34944/ 

`var Component = dict[foo];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can assign to variable reference to component and then render it

```
var One = () => {
  return <div>One</div>;
}

var Two = () => {
  return <div>Two</div>;
}

var dict = {
  one: One,
  two: Two
};

var key = 'one';
var Component = dict[key];

var Main = () => {
  return <Component />;
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/34945/)